# Can I run a VPN faster than internet using custom router + optimized protocol other than TCP/IP?

Tags: routing, vpn, network, isp, transport-protocol

1. If I make a VPN using a custom, optimized hardware router, running a customized routing protocol much more efficient than TCP/IP, put it in place of the router my ISP gave me, then is it possible to get a much faster internet connection speed? (not considering the rate limit of ISP throttling)

Someone told me the answer is yes, because if the routing protocol is really efficient, it will have fewer packet hops so connection speed will be faster than the "regular" internet on TCP/IP. But I think the routing and packet hopping are controlled by ISP, so even if the protocol on my router is efficient, as long as ISP isn't running this efficient protocol, it won't have any impact?

2. What if there are many people running this customized efficient VPN, forming a P2P network (with the optimized routing), will the result be different if I now connect into this P2P network? 
   My guess is no, because as long as the connection depends on ISP, the routing will be controlled by the ISP, so the max connection speed can never be faster than "not using VPN and running TCP/IP", right?

Comment: I guess the only way how a VPN can be "faster" than internet is if and only if the VPN uses heavy traffic compression. It wouldn't be faster for any data though, but you may get more speed overall.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing protocols do not route packets, they simply populate routing tables in routers, and they have nothing to do with how fast packets are routed. Each router routes packets individually, regardless of any other packets, and it does so based on its routing table.

Routing on the Internet is done by IP (after all, IP stands for *Internet* Protocol), so using a different protocol would not work on the Internet, unless it is tunneled in IP packets. A VPN simply encapsulates your packets inside other packets (tunnel), and it is the outer IP packets that are routed.

The outer IP packets will have the same number of hops, with the same delays and speed, but the inner packets only see one hop (the tunnel, itself).

Comment: So, even if there are many optimized hardware VPNs running that efficient protocol, forming a P2P network but still depends on ISP, it won't be any faster than the "regular internet connection"? What if I'm accessing the content hosted on a VPN node within this P2P network, will it be faster on this P2P network than without it?

Comment: It may even be slower because your MTU will go down. The MTU will be reduced by the VPN header size. A network will only transport so many bits per second, and the only thing you can do about that is to reduce the number of bits, e.g. data compression.